# Global find and replace within all stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssms

Is it possible within SSMS to find a reference within the stored procedures of a database and replace that text?

For example: for our reporting purposes we have a parameterised 'master' data retrieval stored procedure that is called by multiple other stored procedures to output data in specific ways. However, if we update the 'master' stored procedure's name, we need to visit every calling stored procedure and rename the reference to it.

This is a long and time consuming task. Is there a way to achieve this with an automated process? The standard SSMS find/replace appears to require the documents that need searching/modifying to be opened in SSMS before it will reference them.

Comment: No, but this is when things like database projects and deployments are invaluable.

Comment: Why would you update the master stored procedures name?

Comment: That is an example. It does happen occasionally that items need renaming (as their usage or function changes over time) to better reflect their purpose or function.

Comment: Funny we were just discussing that at work today, and some people think the gains of renaming database objects isn't worth the pain of doing so. I haven't made up my mind yet.

Comment: We have an object call ReportDaets in a database, @DaleK, and despite the typographical error, I'm too "scared" to fix it as I know something will be missed and break.

Comment: You can rename the procedure and create an SYNONYM called the old name that points to the new name, i do it sometimes when there's too much hassle to fix all the places. This is mostly transparent, unless you do weird things like checking object type metadata and expecting it to be a procedure.

Comment: Looks like I am not the only one in the 'renaming dilema' boat. The problems start when you have a system that grows over the years. I am torn between making a database with clear/useful/relevant Stored Procedure names and just not touching them.

Comment: You can use `select * from sys.sql_modules where definition LIKE '%YourProc%'` to find all relevant code.

Comment: Yeah, finding them isn't a problem. It's just the faff of manually finding and replacing.

Comment: You could get the code for the procedure affected from sys.sql_modules into a string, perform replace of the name, drop the original procedure and execute the replaced string to recreate it with a new name. it will probably work fine unless you do a lot of dynamic code building or there are clashing procedure names ie. you replace spProcedureDoesSomething to spProcedureDoesSomethingElse and there's another procedure called spProcedureDoesSomethingOrOther already

Comment: With a VS Database Project, the master proc can be renamed with a refactoring and all references will be renamed too.